# Python Turtle graphics in Ubuntu issue

Tags: graphics, python

I Use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3 with the additional backports PPA to get LTS.

I started to use Python Turtle graphics (to back to my old but loved Logo programming language), and I found and issue:

Each time I start the turtle graphics, the turtle north is to my right side hand (90 degrees to the right of the expected heading).

Is it by default?

Can I change this behaviour (to put the turtle north to the top of my screen)? How?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

We have to use the command:

```
mode("logo")
```

With this the turtle starts with its north up to the upper side of the graphics screen.